# Android Retrofit + Google Places API (text search)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, retrofit2

I am trying to obtain places according to a given query. I implemented the following interface.

```
 @GET("api/place/textsearch/json?key=MY_API_KEY")
Call<PlaceResponse> getNearbyPlacesByText(@Query("query") String query, @Query("location") String location, @Query("radius") int radius);
```

Then I call this method like this

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiInterface service = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
 Call<PlaceResponse> callByText = service.getNearbyPlacesByText("psí" + "škola", currentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + currentLocation.getLongitude(), PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
```

Then I am retrieving result.

```
 callByText.enqueue(new Callback<PlaceResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PlaceResponse> call, Response<PlaceResponse> response) {
            List<Place> places = response.body().getResults();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of places received: " + places.size());
            setMarkers(type, places, googleMap, context);

        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PlaceResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }

    });
```

But I get more results that dont match to the given query (I get 20 places). I tried in Postman with the URL [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=psí+škola&location=49.188963,16.532183&radius=50000&key=MY_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=ps%C3%AD+%C5%A1kola&location=49.188963,16.532183&radius=50000&key=MY_KEY)

I am not sure if I set the url correctly in my code.

Thanks for any advice
I got only 8 places which is correct number. I am not sure if I

Answer (score 1):

You can set logging in Retrofit and check what is being sent (example in Kotlin).

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging)

Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .client(httpClient.build())
        .build()
        .create(ApiDao::class.java)
```